# How to route all events a UIElement recieves to a single function regardless of their type?

Tags: .net, xaml, winui-3

Normally the binding of event handlers to a particular event is done in XAML itself, like this :

```
<button onClick="clickHandler"/>
```

Here something else is checking the type of the events and if it finds that its a click, it gets sent to clickHandler(). But how to do you implement it so that I get to do this filtering myself ?

I found out that you can create generic event handlers that can be subscribed to any kind of event, but is there like a master handler for a xaml element that would just send all events it recieves into a function, something like :

```
<button allEvents="allEventsHandler"/>
```

Comment: "Here something else is checking the type of the events" - what is "something else" in this context?

Comment: _"but is there like a master handler for a xaml element that would just send all events it recieves into a function, something like :"_ - I think you mean "events it **raises**" rather than "receives", right?

Comment: @Dai I dont exactly know, but something necessarily is checking if an event is a click or not to then send it to m its appropriate handler, and what do you mean by "event it raises" ?

Comment: I asked because I wasn't sure if you were referring to _Routed Events_ or "normal" CLR events.

Comment: @Dai i am trying to get all events targeted at an element, but routed events come as arguments only after you have assigned it to a specific event in XAML like onClick or PointerPressed

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a catch-all event handler.

Comment: Have a look at [XAML controls; bind to a C++/WinRT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property#implement-booksku) which shows how to implement an event.